# Is it possible to reload a new url into WKWebView after initial loading?

Tags: ios, swift, ios13

I am using WKWebView in a simple ios 13 app. I want to be able to open another url based on a user interaction with my app.

Here is the code in my ViewController

```
    var url:String = "https://example.com";

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let notificationName = Notification.Name("updateWebView")
        updateWebView()
    }

    @objc func updateWebView() {
        guard let url = URL(string: url) else {
            print("Invalid URL")
            return
        }
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        newWebView.load(request)
    }
```

I have set up in sceneDelegate code that updates the url in the view controller, looks something like so:

```
let yourViewController = self.window?.rootViewController as? ViewController
        yourViewController?.passData(newUrl)
```

I can see the url string being updated in viewController class as a result with the debugger. However When It runs through the following code block:

```
    func passData(_ data : String?) {
        self.data = data
        guard let url = URL(string: url) else {
            print("Invalid URL")
            return
        }
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        newWebView.load(request)

    }
```

The console log the following message:

```
2019-10-15 20:33:28.886512+0100 SamplerApp[59216:7409192] [ProcessSuspension] 0x600000c936c0 - WKProcessAssertionBackgroundTaskManager: Ignored request to start a new background task because the application is already in the background
```

I would expect this to load the new url inside my WKWebView in my app but instead the code does not seem to do anything just log the message

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is go through `WKWebView.evaluateJavaScript()`.

```
webView.evaluateJavaScript("window.location = 'https://www.google.com';", completionHandler: nil)
```

What this does is go through JavaScript instead of Swift. It 'fools' Swift into thinking that the webpage wants to go to a different URL.

Be sure to substitute `webView` for your own `WKWebView` and https://www.google.com for whatever website you want to redirect the user to.

Comment: `window.location` will push a new page into the webview stacks, so I use `window.location.replace` instead. it's only replace the url and refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

By reading your title, I believe you're trying to load a new URL when the first URL is loaded.

Example:

> on viewDidLoad() load "https://google.com", then when "https://google.com" is successfully loaded, you want to load other URL like "https://stackoverflow.com".

If that's really the case, you can just simply use the WKNavigationDelegate's function:

`webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!)`

That function will be trigger when the URL is completely loaded.